# Need help to prove an identity for inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, inner-products

Show that the following identity holds for vectors in any inner product space:
$$
\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = \frac{1}{4}\left(\| \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}\|\right)^2 - \frac{1}{4}\left(\| \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}\|\right)^2.
$$

The "in any inner product space" is quite confusing for me.

Comment: True in inner product spaces over $\mathbb R$ but not true in inner product spaces over $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

By definition we have

$$\left|u+v \right|^2=\left< u+v,u+v\right>=\left< u,u+v\right>+\left< v,u+v\right>=$$

$$=\left< u,u\right>+\left< u,v\right>+\left< v,u\right>+\left< v,v\right>$$